# Could i use couchbase for token generation and validation systems

Tags: couchbase

I am designing a high volume service which essentially works as a token creation and validation service. Today we use SQL based databases which are fast failing to scale and the alternative that we are looking at is Couchbase server (memcached). However, the use case is the token generated by this service is sent to other services where the token will be used for authentication. If the replication is not fast enough, the authentication fails. Is there a simpler means to achieve this either via code or any other alternatives is also welcome. This seems to us to be a "read-your-own-write" use case.

Comment: I really like Couchbase, is fast for replication if that is what you are in need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no consistency API for XDCR right now. It's probably somewhere on the dev roadmap, because it's one of the commonly requested features.

If you want to get RYOW consistency across data centers, our only option is to write to all the DCs simulataneously from the application code. Of course, it's not atomic, but you can work around that somewhat by waiting for all the clusters to acknowledge the write before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstanding what replication is for in Couchbase. Couchbase is strongly consistent for standard data operations. If you write a document or key/value pair, you can immediately read that object. No waiting for replication. The use case you are talking about is a very common one for Couchbase.

The only things that are eventually consistent in Couchbase are XDCR, for obvious reasons, and reading from views. Even then, this can be minimized with proper cluster sizing.

Comment: Thats what i thought. However, would it be possible to ensure consistency across data centers too (XDCR) or is there a means to target a specific DC in case the original get() didnt work.  

For example:  
    String value = client.get(key)
    if(value==null){
    client.get(key,"DC1");
    }
    
  Is something like the above possible. I am using Java based couchbase-client. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: what you can have is internal cluster replication. one node stores the master copy while 1, 2 or 3 other nodes store a replica copy. the java client allows you to do a `getFromReplica` in case the original get doesn't work. XDCR is maybe more targeted at things like disaster backup site and such

Comment: Today there is no built in mechanism for the SDK to be able to recognize that the primary cluster is down and to instead use another cluster that is being replicated to via XDCR. I know of people that wrote their own mechanism to do this in their code.

This functionality to have an XDCR aware SDK has been requested of the SDK team.